# Link text toggle jquery (Collapsible Panels)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I have several Collapsible panels on one page triggered by a href links, and using php the first is set to active(open) when the user lands on the page.

Using jquery I'm trying to toggle the text in the links.

```
$(".btn[data-toggle='collapse']").click(function() {
   $(this).text($(this).text() == 'Close' ? 'More' : 'Close');  
 });
```

But the first link which is open is working in reverse, so when the user clicks(to collapse the panel) it displays Close instead of More.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

HTML:

```
   <a class="btn" id="collapsible" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse535">Close</a>
   <div id="collapse535" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
      <!--Content-->
   </div>

   <a class="btn" id="collapsible" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse536">More</a>
   <div id="collapse536" class="panel-collapse collapse ">
      <!--Content-->
   </div>


   <a class="btn" id="collapsible" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse537">More</a>
   <div id="collapse537" class="panel-collapse collapse ">
      <!--Content-->
   </div>
```

Comment: Seems to work fine: http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/5dDft/. Is your jQuery within a document ready call?

Answer (score 0):

Toggle it on load:

```
$(function() {
    $(".btn[data-toggle='collapse']:first").text("Close");
});
```